# Blaze Melee Attacks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I summoned a blaze with its speed, health and attack attributes enhanced, and while fighting it (multiple times) I noticed that sometimes it could run up to me and insta-kill me (it didn't have the fire around it, so it wasn't a fireball). I'm thinking it has something to do with the enhanced speed / attack, but **can a normal blaze melee attack?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blaze) link says that Blazes have two attacks: **Fireball** (3/5/7 damage for easy/normal/hard difficulty level) and **Contact** (Melee attack, 4/6/9 damage for according difficulty levels)

Note: All damage is counted in half-hearts

Comment: Are those damage values in hearts or half-hearts?